# Find a decomposition $V = W \oplus X$ for which (1) $W$ has finite codimension, (2) $W \subset S_1 \cap S_2$ and (3) $X \supset T_1 + T_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

This is exercise 3.14 from Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra.

Let $V$ be a vector space with $V = S_1 \oplus T_1 = S_2 \oplus T_2$.

Suppose that $S_1$ and $S_2$ have finite codimension. Hence, by the previous exercise, so does $S_1 \cap S_2$. Find a direct sum decomposition $V = W \oplus X$ for which (1) $W$ has finite codimension, (2) $W \subset S_1 \cap S_2$ and (3) $X \supset T_1 + T_2$.

I think we need to find some $W$ smaller than $S_1 \cap S_2$, so I thought about an intersection with $T_1$ or $T_2$ but then we cannot have $X$ greater than $T_1 + T_2$. I've been trying to work this out but got stuck for a while. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $S:=S_1\cap S_2$ and $T=T_1+T_2$. We can write $S=(S\cap T)\oplus W$, and $V/T=((S+T)/T)\oplus \bar X$. Let $X$ be the preimage of $\bar X$ in $V$, so $T\subset X$. Then $V=S+T+X=S+X$ and $(S+T)\cap X=T$. Thus $W\cap X\subset S\cap X\subset S\cap T$, so $W\cap X=0$. Also, $V=S+X=W+(S\cap T)+X=W+X$. This gives $V=W\oplus X$ as required.

Comment: How do we know that the codimension of W i.e. the dimension of X is finite here?

Comment: Write $V=Y\oplus S=Y\oplus(S\cap T)\oplus W$. You have already shown that $Y$ is finite dimensional, and since $T$ is finite dimensional, so too is $S\cap T$.

Comment: Why does $W \cap X = \{0\}$ follow? I see you've only established that $S \cap X = S \cap T$, but not that both equal the zero subspace.

Comment: On line 5 I write that $W\cap X$ is contained in $S\cap T$. Thus it is contained in $W\cap S\cap T$, which we know is zero.